# how to add a column to a jTable and populate on the fly

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jtable

i have a Jtable with 4 columns and 6 rows and a jButton. when the jButton is clicked a query runs and the results are stored in a string variable. after the query has successfully completed additional code s called to add a column to the existing jTable. My problem is how do i then populate the newly created column with data from the String variable. Am using the following code below

```
for(int col = 0; col<jTable2.getRowCount(); col++){ 
                 TableColumn c = new TableColumn();
                                    c.setHeaderValue("Test");
                                    ((DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel()).addColumn(c);
                                    jTable2.setValueAt("100", col, 12);
                 }
```

this works but the problem is that the code also adds additional columns that are equivalent to the set condition in the forloop. how to i get it to only add one column and populate as much as the condition set in the forloop without also add multiple columns. I know my problem comes from the forloop but i do not know how to solve it.

can onion assist

Comment: @KDM thanx problem solved

Comment: Deleted the comment and added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the column outside the for loop and set values in the loop for each row.